# Summing up number values extracted from one cell using rexexextract or regexreplace

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-group

I have numbers like the sample below stored in one cell:

> First:
> [9miles 12lbs weight 1g Raw]
> Second:
> [1miles 3lbs weight 7g Raw]
> Third:
> [20miles 6lbs weight 3g Raw]

I'd like to extract the numbers, sum them up () and place them in another cell in the same row. So far I can only manage to extract the first instance of regexp using regexextract formula. Is this even possible?

Desired outcome:

> [30miles 21lbs weight 11g Raw]

Comment: Will you be trying to process just one cell? Many in a column? Will there always be three listings per cell (i.e., First: Second: Third:), or might some cells have only one element while others have three or five, etc.? Are the actual words "First," "Second," "Third" (etc.) actually in the strings? As you can see, there are still a lot of unanswered questions. It usually aids clarity and efficiency if you share a sample spreadsheet with, say, 5 or 10 rows of realistic data as well as the manually-entered results you'd like to see for each.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, ":")), " "), "\d+")*1, 0), 
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col4)"), 2)
```

[image]

---

[image]